# Checkbox value to database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

On page skilledHandyman, I have a handyman_id stored from a previous page and a form with checkboxes with list of jobs available, what I want to do is to update foreign key job_id in "handymen" table using whatever checkbox has been selected by taking job_id from table "jobs". Value of job_id is in the checkbox as it can be seen in the code, it just has to be taken and update a job_id foreign key within handyman. I have set up relationships hasMany with jobs table and belongsTo from job to handyman. This is what I have at the moment but it obviously doesn't work as intended.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('skilledHandyman', 'Add Job')
        @section('header2')
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{url('assignjob')}}">Assign job</a></li>
            </ul>
        @show
@section('content')
    <h1>Handyman details</h1>
<ul>
    <li>First Name:{{$skilledHandyman->first_name}}</li>
    <li>Last Name:{{$skilledHandyman->last_name}}</li>
    <li>Street:{{$skilledHandyman->street}}</li>
    <li>Postcode:{{$skilledHandyman->postcode}}</li>
    <li>Town:{{$skilledHandyman->town}}</li>
    <li>Skills:{{$skilledHandyman->skills}}</li>
</ul>

    <form action="{{url('skilledHandyman')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
     @foreach ($jobs as $job)
        <div>
            <label>{{$job->name}}</label>
            <input type='checkbox' value='{{$job->id}}' name='jobs[]'/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Assign Job">
</form>
@endsection
```

---

```
function jobassign(Request $request, $id)
{
    $job = Handyman::where('handyman_id', $handymanId)->update(['job_id', $request->job_id]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans('Handyman has been successfully assigned to this job.'));
}
function skilledHandyman($handymanId)
{
    $skilledHandyman = Handyman::find($handymanId);
    $jobs = Job::all();
    return view('layouts/skilledHandyman', ['jobs' => $jobs, 'skilledHandyman' => $skilledHandyman]);
```

### }

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('home', 'HandymanController@home');

Route::get('search', 'HandymanController@search');

Route::get('details/{skill}', 'HandymanController@details');

Route::get('skilledHandyman/{handymanId}', 'HandymanController@skilledHandyman');

Route::post('jobassign', 'HandymanController@jobassign');

//Route::get('assignjob/{handymanId}', 'HandymanController@assignJob');

Route::get('addjob', 'HandymanController@addJob');

Route::post('addjform', 'HandymanController@addjForm');

Route::get('jobs', 'HandymanController@jobs');

Route::get('jobsdetails/{jobId}', 'HandymanController@jobsdetails');

Route::get('deletejob', 'HandymanController@deleteJob');

Route::post('deletejform', 'HandymanController@deletejForm');
```

### });

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('postcode');
        $table->string('town');
        $table->string('skills');


        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
----

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('handymen_job_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('job_id');
    });
}
```

}
If any other files are needed I will update the page when requested, please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this**

```
 <input type='checkbox' value='{{$job->id}}' name='jobs[]'/>
```

**to**

```
  <input type='checkbox' value='{{$job->id}}' name='job_id'/>
 <input type="hidden" name="handymanid" value="{{$skilledHandyman->id}}">
```

and in the **controller**

```
    function jobassign(Request $request)
    {
         $job_id = $request->input('job_id');
         $handymanId = $request->input('handymanid');
        $job = Handyman::where('id', $handymanId)->update(['job_id', $job_id]);
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans('Handyman has been successfully assigned to this job.'));
    }
```

in ur routes file
change the form action

```
<form action="{{url('jobassign')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Hey thank you for reply, I have changed the code according to your alterations and I get this: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:                                                                                                                        Link looks like this:http://localhost/assign2/public/skilledHandyman?_token=9Ogd3aZELhWdfDD9ykWhqCnU4fzjTnLuxZIGuW6F&handymanid=Plumber&handymanid=Plumber&handymanid=Plumber&job_id=4&handymanid=Plumber&submitBtn=Assign+Job, any suggestions on that one?

Comment: share ur routes file

Comment: One last problem, when I click submit button i get: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `handymen` set `0` = job_id, `1` = 2, `updated_at` = 2016-04-14 08:10:49 where `id` = 1). I have added my databases, job_id is column 10 and that's the only column that needs updating

Comment: i updated my answer i changed  Handyman::where('handymen_id', $handymanId) because its only  "id" on the schema  and updated ur migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109122/discussion-between-achraf-khouadja-and-przemek-wojtas).

Comment: I get the same error message when I have updated my migration

Comment: Yes, spelling mistake is in your code I managed to catch it. $job = Handyman::where('id', $handymanId)->update(['job_id', $job_id]); and should be $job = Handyman::where('id', $handymanId)->update(['job_id' => $job_id]);

Comment: yea ofc   here i usualy dd(); every thing to check where is the error and fix it!  so such case im im blind